# Accepting Confirm() Popup With Python 3 and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Image of a JavaScript `Confirm()` Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkAQl.png)

I have tried many different methods to accept this using **only** selenium and python, but I am having trouble.  Many of the other posts out there only handle the `prompt()` and `alert()` JavaScript functions, but how do I handle a `confirm()` function with selenium?  The `confirm()` function test output is shown above!  Thank you for your help!

See example of `confirm()` JavaScript function for testing: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can disable those with:

```
driver.execute_script(" window.confirm = () => true ")
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you automatically accept these!  This code does not work in my case.